# When getting data from JTable, should I use parameters in fillReport method?

Tags: java, jtable, jasper-reports

I am currently writing simple java application, that reads data from csv to jTable and generate report (.jrxml -> .jasper).

I am **collecting parameters in ArrayList of maps** like so:

```
[{Description = 'qwerty', Title = 'asdfg', Amount = 1800},   
{Description = 'uiop', Title = 'zxcv', Amount = 2500},    
{Description = 'desc', Title = 'mnb', Amount = 510}]
```

**How can i pass it to fillReport method** (it requires java.util.map)?
Or maybe i have to use fields instead of parameters?

EDIT:
Here You have expected output - filled jTable and data from it in jasperView:

[image]

**Here is my code - i get dataSource from jTable:**

```
JRDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource(dataTable.getModel());
            try {
                JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("citibank_customReport.jrxml");
                JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("citibank_customReport.jasper", listOfParameters, dataSource);
                JasperViewer.viewReport(print, true);
            }
```

Unfortunately, **fillReport method doesn't understand arrays of hashmaps**. How can i correct it?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I tried to improve my question, maybe it is now easier to understand the exact problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks, you do not need to use params, see the answer, you already have all the data in your dataSource that you are passing to the fillManager

Answer (score 2):

You do **not** need to use the parameters, you already have the **data in your `dataSource`** that you are already passing to the `JasperFillManager`

You simple need to define fields with same name and class as your columns in the `JTable` model `dataTable.getModel()` in your jrxml (report).

**Example** (columnName is `col1` and it is a `java.lang.String`)

```
<field name="col1" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

jasper-reports will iterate in detail band all the rows in this model and set current columns value to the fields, hence you should put the `textField` referencing the field `$F{col1}` in the detail band.

Comment: So i have to change all $P(parameters) in my report design to $F(fields) and dataSource will provide the answer. One more queston - fillReport method requires: jasper report, PARAMETERS and dataSource. What i have to do with second parameter of this method?

Comment: The datasource (3 param) iterates on detail band, the parameter (2 param) are fixed values that you can send to report, example title of report, path to images etc.

Comment: Understanding the difference between "parameter" and "field" in report design resolved my problem :) Now JasperViewer shows what i expected :)